# dijit.Dialog not redisplaying in IE7 and IE8

Tags: dojo

Using Dojo verions 1.3.2.  The following code is working fine in FF and Chrome, but works sporadically in IE7/8.
I'm grabing a Dialog that already being displayed and just wanting to change its contents.  The oDialogContents is always exactly the same, working or not.
What ends up happening is the Dialog disappears but the underlay stays so a user is forced to do a refresh to get page working again.

```
function showDialog(oDialogContents) {
 var dialogBox = dijit.byId(DIALOG_PAGE);
 dialogBox.attr("style","width: 400px;");
 dialogBox.attr("content", oDialogContents);
 dialogBox.show();
}
```

Comment: are you saying that after you execute the above code and the user attempts to close the dialog, the underlay is left behind? Do you have a page where we can see this happening?

Comment: I was trying to update the contents of the dialog without closing it.  However the dialog would just disappear and the overlay was still in place.  I ended up simply doing a .hide(), changing the contents and then a .show().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by adding this after changing content:

```
// new content not showing in IE7/8 unless we hide the dialog first 
if( dojo.isIE !== undefined )
{
    this._dialog.hide();
    this._dialog.show();
}

this._dialog.layout(); // re-centre in case width changed
```

Basically the dijit needs to be hidden and shown again for IE users.